# What is the difference between fibrogenesis and fibrosis?

Tags: pathology, pathogenesis

Fibrosis is the formation of excess fibrous connective tissue in an organ or tissue in a reparative or reactive process.
I used the word "fibrogenesis" as the outcome of acute inflammation (healing).
My colleges use the word "fibrosis".
The fibrogenesis seems to be used with the emphasises of the genetic part.

**What is the difference between fibrogenesis and fibrosis?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a note, the suffix -genesis refers to the development or production of something, while the suffix -osis can be roughly translated as '...a current state of...' something.

Answer (score 1):

I would say fibrosis represents an abnormal accumulation of fibrous tissue usually collagen fibres. Where as fibrogenesis is the process of formation of fibrous tissues be it collagen, reticulin, elastic, oxytalan..